Centering tikz graphic in OpTeX
I make this graphic with tikz in OpTeX
\fontfam[Fira]

\margins/1 a4 (3.5,2.5,3,3)cm
\typosize[12/18] 

\load[tikz]

{
%\centerline{
%\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
\tikzpicture[domain=-1.045:5.25]
    \draw[very thin,color=gray,step=.52] (-1.045,-1.1) grid (5.4,4.7);

    \draw[->] (-1.2,-1.05) -- (5.5,-1.05) node[right] {$x$};
    %\foreach \i/\j in{-0.525/1,-0.005/2,0.525/3,1.045/4,1.565/5,2.085/6,2.605/7,3.125/8,3.645/9,4.165/10,4.685/11,5.205/12} \draw (\i,-1)--(\i,-1.1) node[below] {\j};
    \foreach \i/\j in {-0.005/2,1.045/4,2.085/6,3.125/8,4.165/10,5.205/12} \draw (\i,-1)--(\i,-1.1) node[below] {\j};
    \draw[->] (-1.045,-1.2) -- (-1.045,4.8) node[above] {$T$};

    %\draw[color=red]    plot (\x,\x)             node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
     % \x r means to convert '\x' from degrees to _r_adians:
    \draw[color=blue,samples=100]   plot (\x,{2*cos(\x r)+2});%    node[right] {$f(x) = 2\cos x + 2$};
%\draw[color=orange] plot (\x,{0.05*exp(\x)}) node[right] {$f(x) = {1\over 20} {\rm e}^x$};
\endtikzpicture
%\end{tikzpicture}
%}
}


I have not been able to center the figure even using the \centerline command. How do I get it centered?

May be the created drawing is wider than we see or think? E.g. there are a number of nodes placed I didn't follow in detail. E.g. try visualizing the boundaries of the tikzpicture. // Also, I suggest having a look into pgfplots, which is dedicated to create such kind of plots.

Oh no, the domain is the one who controls the most and the nodes do not exceed it. Only the grid exceeds the domain a little bit. With\centerline I get an error.

I only can suggest: verify, don't assume. Saves a lot of time ;-)

If you compile the following document:
\fontfam[Fira]

\margins/1 a4 (3.5,2.5,3,3)cm
\typosize[12/18]

\load[tikz]

\centerline{\tikzpicture[domain=-1.045:5.25]
    \draw[very thin,color=gray,step=.52] (-1.045,-1.1) grid (5.4,4.7);

    \draw[->] (-1.2,-1.05) -- (5.5,-1.05) node[right] {$x$};
    \foreach \i/\j in {-0.005/2,1.045/4,2.085/6,3.125/8,4.165/10,5.205/12} \draw (\i,-1)--(\i,-1.1) node[below] {\j};

    \draw[->] (-1.045,-1.2) -- (-1.045,4.8) node[above] {$T$};

    \draw[color=blue,samples=100]   plot (\x,{2*cos(\x r)+2});
\endtikzpicture}

\bye

you get the following error:
Runaway argument?
{\tikzpicture [domain=-1.045:5.25] \draw [very thin,color=gray,step=.52] (-1.045,-1.1) grid (5.4,4.7); 
! Paragraph ended before \centerline was complete.
<to be read again> 
\_par 

The message ! Paragraph ended before […] usually means that you placed an empty line or an explicit \par inside of a non-\long macro. This “feature” is intended to help you find unclosed brace pairs:
[…] end paragraph.

\section{Section Title %% }

Start paragraph […]

but in practice it's mostly just a nuisance. The classical solution to this is to redefine the macro as \long, but in LuaTeX we can use \suppresslongerror, so a complete solution is:
\suppresslongerror=1
\nopagenumbers

\fontfam[Fira]

\margins/1 a4 (3.5,2.5,3,3)cm
\typosize[12/18]

\load[tikz]

\centerline{\tikzpicture[domain=-1.045:5.25]
    \draw[very thin,color=gray,step=.52] (-1.045,-1.1) grid (5.4,4.7);

    \draw[->] (-1.2,-1.05) -- (5.5,-1.05) node[right] {$x$};
    \foreach \i/\j in {-0.005/2,1.045/4,2.085/6,3.125/8,4.165/10,5.205/12} \draw (\i,-1)--(\i,-1.1) node[below] {\j};

    \draw[->] (-1.045,-1.2) -- (-1.045,4.8) node[above] {$T$};

    \draw[color=blue,samples=100]   plot (\x,{2*cos(\x r)+2});
\endtikzpicture}

\bye



Nice +1 // Looks to me like OpTex provides many unpleasant surprises ... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optex

@MS-SPO that's not an unpleasant surprise, that's pretty much standard TeX.

@MS-SPO Plain TeX defines \centerline with just a plain \def, so OpTeX gets it from there. And Plain/OpTeX define \centerline in such a way that it only works for a single paragraph, so it being non-\long is usually correct. LaTeX defines \centerline with \long\def (well, \DeclareRobustCommand actually), but you shouldn't use \centerline in LaTeX anyways.

@Skillmon, thank you. I mean the cause described, not the solution (redefining). Should have been noticed by the OP, shouldn’t it?

@MS-SPO well, if one isn't too familiar with TeX then one might not know the "paragraph ended before..." errors. Still the cause described is pretty much standard TeX, whereas the solution is a less-known LuaTeX feature that's by default switched on in Context and no other format, afaik.
